# How can I get point cloud(with RGB, 2D coordinate on the device, 3D points' coordinate) from View Image on IPad using IPad?

Tags: swift, arkit, point-clouds, lidar

I'm referring to ARKit's sample code 'Visualizing a Point Cloud Using Scene Depth'.

The particle buffer is composed with RGB, 3D coordinate. I don't know the index of the points shown on the device. So, I extracted the point cloud with the ply extension that composed with RGB, 3D coordinate(x,y,z).

But, I want to extract only point cloud that is visible on the device(IPad) with 2D coordinate.

I know, Metal shader functions can transforms mesh data to view data. But, I don't know where the information is stored in.

I would like to know how to save and extract RGB, 3D coordinates on real world generated from lidar, 2D coordinates on device.

'''My code'''

```
func savePointsToFile() {
  guard !self.isSavingFile else { return }
  self.isSavingFile = true
    
    // 1
    var fileToWrite = ""
    let headers = ["ply", "format ascii 1.0", "element vertex \(currentPointCount)", "property float x", "property float y", "property float z", "property uchar red", "property uchar green", "property uchar blue", "property float cx", "property float cy", "property float depth", "property uchar alpha", "element face 0", "property list uchar int vertex_indices", "end_header"]
    for header in headers {
        fileToWrite += header
        fileToWrite += "\r\n"
    }
    
    // 2
    for i in 0..<currentPointCount {
    
        // 3
        let point = particlesBuffer[i]
        let colors = point.color
        
        // 4
        let red = colors.x * 255.0
        let green = colors.y * 255.0
        let blue = colors.z * 255.0
        
        // 5
        let pvValue = "\(point.position.x) \(point.position.y) \(point.position.z) \(Int(red)) \(Int(green)) \(Int(blue)) \(point.texCoord.x) \(point.texCoord.y) \(point.depth)  255"
        fileToWrite += pvValue
        fileToWrite += "\r\n"
    }
    // 6
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    let file = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("ply_\(UUID().uuidString).ply")
    
    do {
    
        // 7
        try fileToWrite.write(to: file, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
        self.isSavingFile = false
    } catch {
        print("Failed to write PLY file", error)
    }
}
```